# Invalid argument supplied for foreach in Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 776

Tags: magento-1.8, error, upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0, eav

After upgrading magento to 1.8.1.0 (from 1.7.) I am now seeing this error in my system.log:

> 2014-05-26T10:39:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 776

Line 776 of `Abstract.php`:

```
foreach ($fields as $alias=>$field) {
    if (isset($this->_joinFields[$alias])) {
        throw Mage::exception(
            'Mage_Eav',
            Mage::helper('eav')->__('A joint field with this alias (%s) is already declared', $alias)
        );
    }
    $this->_joinFields[$alias] = array(
        'table' => $tableAlias,
        'field' => $field,
    );
}
```

Anybody else seeing this error and is it a bad one or can it be ignored?

Comment: can you provide more context? What code calls that method? What page? Do you have any extensions that might generate this?

Comment: It is part of a public function called "joinTable", however I can't find any template that calls this function so I have no idea how to track this down...

The error usually pops up every other minute, sometimes every other second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the problem too and your comment hinted me to the right spot.

As you said the error comes from the public function `joinTable()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php`.

Unlike you I have used `joinTable()` in a Module of mine.

The head of that function says the following

```
 * @param string|array $table
 * @param string $bind
 * @param string|array $fields
 * @param null|array $cond
 * @param string $joinType
 * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function joinTable($table, $bind, $fields = null, $cond = null, $joinType = 'inner')
```

Problem here is that `$fields` should not be of type string as said in the `@param` because it is used in a `foreach` loop.

I modified my call of `joinTable()` to not give a string, but an array with a string. No log entries so far.

My guess for you would be that some module uses `joinTable` and passes just a string for `$fields`. Are you able to debug into your code? That way you would have the stacktrace and could determine which modules fault that was.

EDIT:

I've looked further into it to anser your last questions:

"**is it a bad one**"

No. The join will still work, because later on, deep in call structure reachable from line 817 of `Abstract.php` there is a check if `$fields` (until then called `$cols`) is an array (`/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php` line 411) and if not will be converted into one for further processing (this is missing in `Abstract.php`).

"**can it be ignored**"

I'd say yes. It crams your log, but not disabling your project (at this point).

Answer (score 1):

This code resolved your problem,

Add before -> foreach ($fields as $alias=>$field)

```
if (!is_array($fields)){
  $fields_temp=$fields;
  $fields=array();
  $fields[]=$fields_temp;
}
```